# Nginx, try_files & multiple folders with front controllers

Tags: php, nginx, config

I can't wrap my head around Nginxs' `try_files`. Recently I installed Nginx in favour of Apache on my development machine. How I used to work was like this: I'd bootstrap a project in a subfolder of my http directory. If this involved laravel, wordpress, codeigniter or any other framework that's using a front controller to make URLs more readable, I'd add a .htaccess in that directory to rewrite all non-existing paths to index.php.

Supposedly, this is very simple on Nginx: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string` and it should work. However, all this does is redirect everything to the index.php in the `$document_root`. Example:

File structure:

1. `http/clients/cms/public/index.php` front controller
2. `http/clients/cms/public/some/application/url` request uri with the parameters `some`, `application` and `url`.
3. `http/clients/cms/public/images/image.png` a static file.
4. `http/clients/blog/index.php` another front controller
5. `http/clients/blog/wp-content/image.png` another static file
6. `http/clients/blog/some-article-title` a 'pretty url' that should be directed to `4`

Now, hen a request is made to `2`, try_files detects that /some, /some/application and /some/application/url don't exist. It will now redirect to /index.php. I would expect that it would redirect to index.php in the `public/` directory, but it doesn't. Instead, it redirects to the index.php in the $document_root (which happens to contain a `phpinfo();` call, so it's easy to see that it goes wrong..).

A solution would be to create multiple location blocks in my Nginx config, but I'm not liking that. It would add a significant amount of extra work to my bootstrapping process.

Is there a way to use try_files in the directories so that it works exactly like the apache alternative?

My config file:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         localhost,imac.local;

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    rewrite_log         on;

    root                /Volumes/Storage/Fabian/Dropbox/Sites;
    index               index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        #echo $request_filename;
        #break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index               index.php;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info        ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                     fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: do you have 2 sites? cms and blog ? are they sub directories of the same domain ? `example.com/blog`,`example.com/cms`? or subdomains `blog.example.com` ..

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady no, it's just localhost. So a lot of different apps on localhost (cms, blog, app, app2, etc)

Comment: so `http://localhost/cms` ? or like `http://cms.local` or `.dev` or something like that ? just to know if you need a new server block or a location block